# Add left only border in Data bar Series on SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Hope someone could help me how to add a border(red) like below. This is a databar chart. I am adding a border on the properties but it shows border to all corners. I can't specify it to only one corner.

[image]

Design View

[image]

If it's really not possible. can someone suggest other solution? It should be dynamic too. It should be aligned with the blue ones. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing (maybe a design view might help) but have you tried a **StripLine**? http://realworldsql.com/2012/06/07/ssrs-striplines/

Comment: Can't find the stripline property. Maybe because it's a data bar not a chart. I added the design view in my post now.

Comment: On the DataBar properties window (not the popup) click on the ellipses for **ChartArea**, then the **Values Axes collection** ellipses to get to the **Stripline Collection***.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure why its not working for you.. its a straight forward

1. Set BorderStyle: Default None & Left:Solid
2. BorderColor: Red

Sorry, I can't see the image uploaded with Question, due to some firewall .. you can try with above steps

Comment: In databar series, borderstyle property can't be expand unlike in other charts that you can set border only in Bottom,Top,Left or Right. Here you can only set it as Solid then it will have border on bottom,left and top, the right border is not showing. not sure why